# Is it a good practice to convert all non ssl references to ssl in a php page by str_replacing the- content in output buffer?

Tags: php, ssl, output-buffering

I needed to replace all the non ssl references in the html output of php. Is it a good practice to do it by doing a str_replace of the contents in the output buffer and flushing it out? Actually there are lots of includes and requires in the php code so it would be really tedious to do it by finding the place where each reference is made. Is there any hard and fast way to work this out? Here's a rough idea of what i'm doing

```
<?php 
ob_start();

// does the logic to generate output html.

$mixedHtml = ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
$finalHtml = str_replace('http:','https:',$mixedHtml);
echo $finalHtml;
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: If the destination of links are resources on your own server, you could set up server to redirect all http request to https ones.

Comment: See [protocol-relative URL](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

Answer (score 2):

Is it a good practice to convert all non ssl references to ssl in a php page by str_replacing the- content in output buffer? --> **No**.

This is because your page might actually need to serve content that contains "http://" and they aren't necessarily links. I'm just saying that there might come a time that you need to output those and due to the str_replace(), your page won't be able to output it.

I have three suggestions:

1. **Output correct links**. If possible, output the correct link (http or https) so you don't need to replace them. You can do that by using a constant or a function that returns whether http or https should be used.
2. **Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace)** so that you will only replace text in certain tags such as `<a> <link> <img> <script>`.
3. **Rely on server redirection**. You can set your server to redirect all http traffic to https so that you don't need to worry about changing the links. When they visit the http link, they will be forwarded to the https link. You can put the following in your **.htaccess** file:

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thank you @rationalboss I'll try the preg_replace instead of str_replace. I've already tried your 1st suggestion, but the problem is that it's a really old project with crappy coding. The 3rd suggestion, i don't think it would take care of image and js src.

Comment: @Hisham the third solution will also take care of images, css and javascript files. its unconditional -- each and every request via HTTP is redirected to HTTPS, no matter what file type.

Comment: isn't preg_replace resource heavy?

Comment: @NabeelKhan it certainly is. output correct links if possible.